# magento will not install on localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, installation

I have recently downloaded Magento onto my computer and I keep getting errors, I have checked my php version and it is 5.6.3 but I still get this error.
Whoops,

> it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.
>
> Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer. Find out how to install Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.

Can anyone advise me on how to go about fixing this any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version do you try to install ? I see 1.9 in your label, you can look at those requirements [here](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) and it doesn't seem that PHP 5.6 is supported.

Comment: what would you recommend I do?

Comment: I think you should downgrade your PHP version to a supported one

Answer (score -1):

Its simple . just create a virtual host and install magento in virtual host pointed directory . you will not get any error and magento will work fine .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post